# Login options don't appear on Ubuntu 18.04, instead I get logged in automatically

Tags: dual-boot, login-screen

When I start Ubuntu 18.04, login options don't appear; it just logs in automatically.

I want to see a login screen and log in from there. How can I fix this?

Comment: This question is about login automatically in 18.04. It is not about getting the GRUB menu to display.

Answer (score 1):

Open *Settings* -> *Details* -> *Users* -> Press the unlock icon in the title bar (it looks like a padlock) and authenticate with your user password to make changes -> toggle *Automatic Login* from ON to OFF. If there are multiple users on your system, then you also need to select the User to disable its automatic login.

Comment: That is not working turn on and off automatic login

Comment: Press the unlock icon (it looks like a padlock) in the title bar to make changes.